# Phonegap build config.xml

Tags: phonegap-build

I have a hybrid app built with PhoneGap. If I compile the app using Android Studio / XCode everything is working fine, but i want to use PhoneGap Build. When starting the app built with PhoneGap on my Android device, it doesn't work. It seems like a permission issue. My app requires internet connection and access to location services. I have no idea on how to include this in my `config.xml`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your config.xml

```
<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" />
<access origin="*"/> 
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="data:*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-intent href="itms:*" />
<allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-intent href="market:*" />
```

The wildcards will allow everything, as per the intent examples you can be more specific.

Comment: doesn't work. It seems like, there is no internet connection available

Comment: hmmm that should work. Can you explain step by step what you are doing, maybe display your config.xml file on here? I assume there is not any conflicting code in the actual build, or any other extensions you have put in place? Is the cordova whitelist plug in loading when you compile on phonegap build?

Comment: from what you said it must be to do with your config.xml file, please can you post it on here.

Comment: hmm, it seems working now ... i tested the app with a old version of a android simulator after updating it works ^^ thanks for helping me out

Comment: awesome! glad to help. If you need anything else with Phonegap Build, let me know, spent wayyyyyyyyyy too much time working things out.